# Method of taking text into entry box and searching for it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to be able enter information into the entry box and then have a function read it and return a statement depending on what was entered. Every time I run the program and try it, I get a failure that says "Type Error can only concatenate str (not "int) to str"

I've tried setting the text entry as a stringvar and then calling it as part of the function to search for that entry variable but it doesn't seem to change anything.

This is my code:

```
E = Entry(top,text='var',textvariable=var,bd=5)
def faultCodes():
    x = E.get()
    for x in E:
        if x == 500 or x == 514:
            print("Follow fault code 9621F4A4.")
        else:
            print("Enter a fault code.")
    label = Label(text=x).place(x=0,y=300)
```

The results I'm looking for is for a user to be able to enter a value of 500 or 514 and have the statement printed.

Comment: What's the full traceback of the error? What line is it on?

Comment: What do you think `for x in E` is going to do, given that `E` is a widget?

Comment: Rassar-error on line 1489, in cget

Bryan-I thought that adding a `for` loop would allow this code to run as log as there is information in the entry box but I realize now I probably don't need that. I just tried taking it out and running the code-I no longer get a failure but it doesn't run the `if` loop either. It just prints the entered information over the submit button.

Comment: which line is 1489 ? Always put full error message (full Traceback) in question - not in comment. There are many useful information. And it will be more useful than text `error on line 1489`

Comment: add a minimal and executable example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create button to run code which will get text from `var.get()` or from `E.get()` and do something

```
E = Entry(top, text='var', textvariable=var, bd=5)
E.pack()

B = Button(top, text='OK', command=faultCodes)
B.pack()

def faultCodes():
    entry_text = var.get()

    if entry_text == "500" or entry_text == "514":
         print("Follow fault code 9621F4A4.")
    else:
         print("Enter a fault code.")

    label = Label(top, text=entry_text)
    label.pack()
```

Or you can bind `<Return>` to `Entry` to run function when you press `Enter` in `Entry`. Tkinter will run function with `event` as argument so function has to get this argument.

```
E = Entry(top, text='var', textvariable=var, bd=5)
E.pack()

E.bind('<Return>', faultCodes)

def faultCodes(event):
    entry_text = var.get()

    if entry_text == "500" or entry_text == "514":
         print("Follow fault code 9621F4A4.")
    else:
         print("Enter a fault code.")

    label = Label(top, text=entry_text)
    label.pack()
```

You can even use both method with the same function if you use `event=None`

Full working example

```
from tkinter import *

def faultCodes(event=None):
    entry_text = var.get()

    if entry_text == "500" or entry_text == "514":
         print("Follow fault code 9621F4A4.")
    else:
         print("Enter a fault code.")

    label = Label(top, text=entry_text)
    label.pack()


top = Tk()

var = StringVar()
E = Entry(top, text='var', textvariable=var, bd=5)
E.pack()

E.bind('<Return>', faultCodes)

B = Button(top, text='OK', command=faultCodes)
B.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

BTW: `var.get()` gives string so I compare with strings "500", "514" - not with integers 500, 514.

---

**EDIT:** example with `Label`

```
from tkinter import *

# --- function ---

def faultCodes(event=None):
    entry_text = var.get()

    if entry_text == "500" or entry_text == "514":
         label['text'] = "Follow fault code 9621F4A4."
    else:
         label['text'] = "Enter a fault code."

# --- main ---

top = Tk()

var = StringVar()
E = Entry(top, text='var', textvariable=var, bd=5)
E.pack()

E.bind('<Return>', faultCodes)

B = Button(top, text='OK', command=faultCodes)
B.pack()

label = Label(top, text='')
label.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** example with dictionary

```
from tkinter import *

data = {
    "500": "Follow fault code 9621F4A4.",
    "514": "Follow fault code 9621F4A4.",
    # ...add more ...
}

# --- function ---

def faultCodes(event=None):
    entry_text = var.get()

    if entry_text in data:
         label['text'] = data[entry_text]
    else:
         label['text'] = "Enter a fault code."

# --- main ---

top = Tk()

var = StringVar()
E = Entry(top, text='var', textvariable=var, bd=5)
E.pack()

E.bind('<Return>', faultCodes)

B = Button(top, text='OK', command=faultCodes)
B.pack()

label = Label(top, text='')
label.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've tried these methods but every time I enter something into the entry box and click the button it returns the same value I entered as a label. I'm assuming this is because the label in the function is set as `label = Label(text=entry_text)`. How do I get it to return the required statements as a label?

Comment: if you need different text in label then use different text in `Label(text="differen text")`

Comment: My problem is that it is not printing the statement that is in the `if` loop in the function. If I enter 500 as the value in the entry box it should print `Follow fault code 9621F4A4.` but instead it's just repeating the entry_text variable. How can I get the loop in the function to actually work correctly?

Comment: as I said before - use `Label(text="Follow fault code 9621F4A4")`

Comment: Do you mean to assign the label in the loop like `label = Label(text="Follow fault code 9621F4A4")` because that returns an error of label being referenced before assignment. If you mean assigning the label as that outside of the loop, then it is not performing as I intended because it will always display that label, regardless of what values are entered.

Comment: I only took your code and you create `Label` in `faultCodes` so I though you know how to use it. What loop ? I don't use loop in my last example. Do you have any loop ?

Comment: see new example in answer. It changes text in label. And it create `Label` only once.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I've explained this poorly since I'm not great at programming. In the faultCodes function I was trying to program a loop that would read what was entered into the entry box and reply based off of the value. For instance, if I entered 500 or 514 I wanted it to return `Follow fault code 9621F4A4.` If I entered anything else it should read `Enter a fault code.` I guess instead of saying loop I should say the `if else` statement but I was going to add more steps once I got this working.

Comment: so now you can see new example in answer - it does what you need. And you can add more `elif`. Or you could use dictionary `{"500": "Follow fault code 9621F4A4", ...}`.

Comment: That new example actually works better but it doesn't seem to recognize what I am entering. I entered both 500 and 514 but it returned `Please enter a fault code.`

Edit: Disregard this. I forgot that I had to treat the entered variable as a string instead of an integer. Thanks a lot for all your help, it is most appreciated.

Comment: I added example with dictionary. It is easier to add new elements to dictionary or read all from file.